# Why i am getting DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=1, RowIndex=2 } in my textbox rather than name of column

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I want to show grid view data in textbox but unable to fetch data where I am Making mistake
using System.Dat

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: You will want to put the `Value` of the cell in the text box, not the cell itself.

Comment: You may need to read column.DataContext value, instead of reading the value of the col